# Changing effect type of fs2.Stream

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, fs2

I'm using doobie which can produce an `fs2.Stream[ConnectionIO, Int]` of database rows (`Int` in my case). The `ConnectionIO[A]` is doobie's internal type.

Given a HKT `F[_]` and `val nt: ConnectionIO ~> F` is there a way to get `fs2.Stream[F, Int]` from `fs2.Stream[ConnectionIO, Int]`?

I didn't find some sort of `mapK` defined for `fs2.Stream`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method you're looking for is called [`translate`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/co/fs2/fs2-core_2.12/2.2.1/fs2-core_2.12-2.2.1-javadoc.jar/!/fs2/Stream.html#translate%5BF2%5Bx%5D%3E:F%5Bx%5D,G%5B_%5D%5D(u:F2%7E%3EG):fs2.Stream%5BG,O%5D), or `translateInterruptible` in some cases.